# How can I go back to the last commit without losing work?

Tags: git

I just made a commit and accidentally left in some files I should have removed. How can I undo this commit without losing any of the work? I want to undo that commit, go in and remove 2 files and then recommit all the changes.

Thanks!

Comment: without losing any of the work? 
I don't know if is possible ^^ but it's good question.
For me, you create other git clone folder, and revert in last commit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to undo anything. As long as you haven't pushed the commit:

```
git commit -a --amend -C HEAD
```

will amend the commit you just made, keeping the same commit message,  committing any updated or deleted (but not untracked new) files.

---

> so if i remove the files and then run that it will add it to the commit?

Yes, and if you want to be super-safe you can `git rm` the files and drop the `-a` flag:

```
git rm files/to/delete
git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

Comment: ok awesome, so if i remove the files and then run that it will add it to the commit?

Answer (score 1):

First stash your current work

> git stash

then start interactive rebase:

> git rebase -i HEAD~5

you will see a list of your commits, e.g:

```
pick ff9c256 Added file manager logic
pick 8e09710 Added file manager UI
```

change 'pick' into 'e' to go into edit mode of your commit eg:

```
e 8e09710 Added file manager UI
```

then add/remove files from commit, edit files you want to change in your commit,

then

> git commit --amend

and in the end

> git rebase --continue

to go to the last commit and

> git stash apply

to restore your current work progress

Comment: What happens if you remove a file from a commit that happened 5 commits ago? it is removed in all future commits?

Comment: If you remove and don't modify that file in later commits, yes. If you change it later you have to resolve conflict.